# Alternative for ImageStore.addImageFromBase64?

Tags: javascript, react-native, base64, crop, image-store

When updating an old React Native application I ran into a problem with legacy code. It uses `ImageStore` `addImageFromBase64()` in one method to:

1. Store Base64 image into the FS
2. **Add white space on top and bottom** (by resizing it)
3. Retrieve it from the FS again as Base64

How should I go about modifying it to achieve the same desired functionality?

The problem is that `addImageFromBase64()` doesn't work on Android.

> Warning: react-native: ImageStore.addImageFromBase64() is not
>   implemented on android

```
  // Resize photo (fill white space on top and bottom)
  static async addWhiteSpace(data) {
    const {
      height,
      width,
      base64Str
    } = data;
    const cropData = {
      offset: {
        x: 0,
        y: - height / 2,
      },
      size: {
        width,
        height: 2 * height
      },
      resizeMode: 'contain'
    };

    const uriResolver = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ImageStore.addImageFromBase64(base64Str, (uri) => {
        resolve(uri)
      }, (err) => {
        reject(err)
      })
    });
    const whitespaceURIResolver = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ImageEditor.cropImage(uriResolver, cropData, (whitespaceURI) => {
        resolve(whitespaceURI)
      }, (err) => {
        reject(err)
      })
    });
    const base64Resolver = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ImageStore.getBase64ForTag(whitespaceURIResolver, (base64) => {
        resolve(base64)
      }, (err) => {
        reject(err)
      })
    });
    return base64Resolver
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved the problem, now it's running on both Android and iOS:

```
  static async addWhiteSpace(data) {
    const {
      height,
      width,
      base64Str
    } = data;
    const cropData = {
      offset: {
        x: 0,
        y: Math.abs(- height / 2),
      },
      size: {
        width,
        height: 2 * height
      },
      resizeMode: 'contain'
    };

    const uriResolver = await RNFS.writeFile(RNFS.CachesDirectoryPath + "temp.png", base64Str, 'base64');
    const whitespaceURIResolver = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ImageEditor.cropImage("file:" + uriResolver, cropData, (whitespaceURI) => {
        resolve(whitespaceURI)
      }, (err) => {
        reject(err)
      })
    });
    const base64Resolver = await RNFS.readFile(whitespaceURIResolver, "base64");
    return base64Resolver
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not done this, but you may be able to load the image into the image editor directly by prefixing `data:image/png;base64,` to the base64 data.
In your case, the call might look like:

```
    ImageEditor.cropImage('data:image/png;base64,'+base64Str, cropData, (whitespaceURI) => etc..
```